# execute sbt task if input files have changed *or* settings have changed

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a task that will generate an output file based on several input files as well as some sbt settings. It's basically like a compiler where the result is determined by both input files and settings such as compiler flags. Therefore I need to regenerate the result if either the input files or the settings have changed.

This seems like a very common thing to me, and while I do have a solution that works, it seems ugly and long-winded. Is there a better (simpler and/or shorter) way to do it?

```scala
import java.nio.file.Path
import sbt.nio.Keys._
import sbt._
import sbt.Keys._
import sbt.nio.file.FileTreeView
import sjsonnew._

class StuffConfig
object StuffConfig {
  implicit val fmt: JsonFormat[StuffConfig] = ??? // omitted
}


object StuffPlugin extends AutoPlugin {
  object autoImport {
    val generateStuff = taskKey[File]("generate Stuff")
    val stuffConfig = settingKey[StuffConfig]("stuff config")
    val stuffInputFiles = settingKey[Seq[Glob]]("stuff inputs")
    val stuffOutput = settingKey[File]("stuff outputs")
  }

  def doTheThings(cfg: StuffConfig, files: Seq[Path]) = ??? // omitted
  
  override def projectSettings: Seq[Def.Setting[_]] = {
    import autoImport._
    Seq(
      generateStuff / fileInputs := stuffInputFiles.value,
      generateStuff := {
        val store = streams.value.cacheStoreFactory.make("stuffCache")
        val filesChanged = generateStuff.inputFileChanges.hasChanges
        val output = stuffOutput.value
        Tracked.inputChanged[StuffConfig, File](store) { (configChanged, config) =>
          if (configChanged || filesChanged || !output.exists) {
            doTheThings(config, FileTreeView.default.list(stuffInputFiles.value).map(_._1))
          }
          stuffOutput.value
        }.apply(stuffConfig.value)
      }
    )
  }
}
```